# Proving an inequality for elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

Let $a$ be a real number less than zero and $w,x,y,z$ real numbers with $w\geq 1, x\geq 2, y\geq 3, z\geq 4$ that have pairwise distances of at least $1$. Given that $$15a^2+6a\sigma _1+4\sigma _2=\sigma _1^2,$$ where $\sigma _1=w+x+y+z$ and $\sigma _2=wx+wy+wz+xy+xz+yz$ are the first two elementary symmetric polynomials in $w,x,y,z$, prove that $$(a+2)^2\geq \frac{2}{3}.$$ As of now, I could not succeed in proving any upper bound on this, partly due to the fact that I only have lower bounds on $w,x,y,z$.

Interpreting the given equation as a quadratic in $a$ or $\sigma _1$ and then deriving inequalities from the determinant did not give any sufficient results either.

Any help or hint is much appreciated.

**NOTE**: An earlier version of this question asked to prove that $4\sigma _2-\sigma _1^2\leq 50$. However, this was just an attempt by me to prove the inequality above since it is a sufficient condition. Unfortunately, it does not hold in general, as proven by Chris Custer.

Answer (score 1):

A little algebra gives that you need to prove $$-6a\sigma_1\le50+15a^2$$.  So we need $\sigma_1\le -\frac {50+15a^2}{6a}$.

But there's no upper bound on $\sigma _1$.  So the inequality doesn't hold, in general...

For instance if $a=-1$ and $\sigma _1=20$, the inequality fails.

Comment: But doesn't your response to my edit now assume just the inequality that you disproved in the first part of your answer?

Comment: @mxian it appears you are correct.

Comment: @mxian btw my "disproof" is incomplete,  as we haven't shown there are $x,y,w$ and $z$ such that the equation above holds...

Comment: I have checked, Wolfram Alpha says there are.

Comment: @mxian nice work...